# splashscreen while loading application in android cordova app

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

We are building a Cordova application and it loads the resources after splash screen. Is there any way in Cordova to load the resources while the splash screen is displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, what you want to do is disable the splash screen auto dismiss and dismiss it in your own code, say in the "deviceready" callback in your application or at some other point when you know your app has built its view and is ready.

You will want to tell the splash plugin not to auto hide the splash screen, by adding this to your config.xml and/or setting the splash delay in there to a very long time:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Then in your JS code when deviceready happens, or whenever you are ready, programmatically dismiss your splash:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

More information on this is available in the [splash screen plugin documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your MainActivity.java file to setup a splashscreen

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen",R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),2000);
}
```

Comment: I am using Cordova splashscreen.. So I dont think I need to set up again . I am getting splashscreen but My resources are being loaded after splashscreen.. I want them to be loaded while the splashscreen is loaded